# DRF: 'dict' object is not callable

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to work with DRf but at some point I got an error saying: `TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable.` This is happening every time i'm sending a list in JSON to the serializer:

```
class EmployeeDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.UUIDField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'full_name', 'email', 'user_tag', 'password')

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):

        for tag_id in validated_data('user_tag'):
            tag = UserTag.objects.get(id=tag_id)
            instance.user_tag.add(tag)

        instance.save()
        return instance
```

My JSON looks like this: 
`{"user_tag":["bc41fbef-7df0-4135-8374-29e35145fedb"]}`

Comment: It's just a guess, but have you tried removing the parentheses in `id = serializers.UUIDField()`?  I would need the full traceback in order to say for sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like the error says, `validated_data` is a dictionary; you don't access those with calling parentheses, you use indexing brackets:

```
for tag_id in validated_data['user_tag']:
```

Answer (score -1):

```
for tag_id in validated_data['user_tag']:
    tag = UserTag.objects.get(id=tag_id.id)
    instance.user_tag.add(tag)`
```